# how to check that radio streaming link is offline/dead in android app

Tags: java, android

I have developed a radio application and its working very fine with multiple streams. The problem here is one of the radio link is currently offline or we can say dead temporarily. This is making my app to stop. 
I have added the Connectivity check also. Its is working when IsConnected but not when link is dead.

Here is my `setOnItemClickListener` of listview where i need to check links are working or not on item select.

```
    lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        mSelectedTrackTitle.setText(stations[position]);
                        nowplaying.setText("Now Playing");
                        mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
                        Resources res = getResources();
                        String[] links = res.getStringArray(R.array.links);
                        String url = links[position];
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            Log.d("abc", "playing and now going to reset : " + url);
                            try {
                                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                                mMediaPlayer.release();
                                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                                mMediaPlayer.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            try {
                                Log.d("abc", "in else part :" + url);
                                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                                mMediaPlayer.start();
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                                    Log.d("error", "what:" + what + " extra:" + extra);
                                    nowplaying.setText("offline");
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        nowplaying.setText("Server is currently offline");
                    }
                }
            }
```

and

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: You are checking just internet connection in isNetworkAvailable(). You need to check whether you are reachable to that Radio Link or not. You need to pass your link in isNetworkAvailable() and write some more logic to of whether that link is reachable or not.

Comment: can you please check the edited code . i need to handle it with Error listener . But its not working.